# What is wrong here?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, spherical-coordinates, electromagnetism

What is wrong in turning this expression in spherical coordinates :

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\vec{r}\, \cos \Theta \,  \sin \Theta \,   \mathrm{d} \Theta  \,   \mathrm{d} \phi   $$

to this :

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos \Theta \, \sin \Theta \,  \mathrm{d} \Theta\int_{0}^{2\pi}\vec{r}\,  \,  \mathrm{d} \phi =  0 \cdot \int_{0}^{2\pi}\vec{r}\,  \,  \mathrm{d} \phi = 0  $$

In other words, why can't I pull out all the $\theta$ terms that are constant relative to the $\phi$ integration ?

Comment: Because $\vec{r}$ depends on $\theta$ and $\phi$

Comment: I guess $\vec{r}$ is a function of $\Theta$ and $\phi$? Then you can pull the $\Theta$ parts out of the inner integral, but you cannot use the property $\int_A f(x) \int_B g(y) dy dx = \left ( \int_A f(x) dx \right ) \left ( \int_B g(y) dy \right )$ since the inner integral in your problem depends on both variables. In other words the error is the first equals sign in the second line, not converting the first line to the LHS of the second line.

Comment: @Ian I understand now, Thank you.